# How to get headphones plug event in UWP

Tags: windows, uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I am writing one UWP app where I need to listen to the headphones plug events when headphone plug in/ plug out from device(PC or Mobile UWP).

I have tried to handle `MediaDevice::DefaultAudioRenderDeviceChanged`
and `Windows::Devices::Enumeration::DeviceWatcher`. 
But neither of them could work as expected.

I can handle the default device changing event with `MediaDevice::DefaultAudioRenderDeviceChanged`. But for headphone plug case, the default device does not change. So the render device change event is not triggered.

`Windows::Devices::Enumeration::DeviceWatcher` cannot catch that event either.

So please help share how I can get the event of headphone plug event in UWP? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have tried to handle MediaDevice::DefaultAudioRenderDeviceChanged and Windows::Devices::Enumeration::DeviceWatcher. But neither of them could work as expected.

You can use  [DeviceWatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.enumeration.devicewatcher.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to handle [DeviceWatcher.Added](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.enumeration.devicewatcher.added.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) or [DeviceWatcher.Removed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.enumeration.devicewatcher.removed.aspx) events.

MainPage.xaml.cpp:

```
using namespace Windows::Devices::Enumeration;
using namespace Windows::UI::Core;

MainPage::MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

void DeviceWatcherCppSample::MainPage::btnClick_Click(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e)
{
    watcher=DeviceInformation::CreateWatcher(DeviceClass::AudioRender);
    handlerAddedToken=watcher->Added += ref new     Windows::Foundation::TypedEventHandler<DeviceWatcher ^, DeviceInformation ^>(this, &DeviceWatcherCppSample::MainPage::OnAdded);

    handlerRemovedToken= watcher->Removed += ref new Windows::Foundation::TypedEventHandler<DeviceWatcher ^, DeviceInformationUpdate ^>(this, &DeviceWatcherCppSample::MainPage::OnRemoved);
    handlerUpdatedToken= watcher->Updated += ref new Windows::Foundation::TypedEventHandler<Windows::Devices::Enumeration::DeviceWatcher ^, Windows::Devices::Enumeration::DeviceInformationUpdate ^>(this, &DeviceWatcherCppSample::MainPage::OnUpdated);
    watcher->Start();
}


void DeviceWatcherCppSample::MainPage::OnAdded(DeviceWatcher ^sender, DeviceInformation ^args)
{
    this->Dispatcher->RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority::Normal, ref new Windows::UI::Core::DispatchedHandler([this, args]()
    {
        tbResult->Text = args->Name +"is Added";
    }));
}


void DeviceWatcherCppSample::MainPage::OnRemoved(DeviceWatcher ^sender, DeviceInformationUpdate ^args)
{
    this->Dispatcher->RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority::Normal, ref new Windows::UI::Core::DispatchedHandler([this, args]()
    {
        tbResult->Text = args->Id + "is Removed";
    }));
}


void DeviceWatcherCppSample::MainPage::OnUpdated(Windows::Devices::Enumeration::DeviceWatcher ^sender, Windows::Devices::Enumeration::DeviceInformationUpdate ^args)
{
    this->Dispatcher->RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority::Normal, ref new Windows::UI::Core::DispatchedHandler([this, args]()
    {
        tbResult->Text = args->Id + "is Updated";
    }));

}
```

MainPage.xaml:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Button Name="btnClick" Click="btnClick_Click">Click Me to Watch</Button>
        <TextBlock Name="tbResult"></TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

And here is the complete Demo: [DeviceWatcherSample](https://github.com/elvisxia/DeviceWatcherSample). Also you can refer to scenario 2 of the [Official Sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/DeviceEnumerationAndPairing).

Comment: Thanks a lot Elvis. It works on Mobile Phone!   But it still does not work on PC since Speaker and Headphone share the same device called "Speakers/Headphones".

Comment: The USB headphones can be detected correctly. The not-USB headphones can't. They can only be detected through `DeviceClass::All` and only the plug-in event triggers the update event, which is not a proper solution for your requirement. So,as far as I know, there is no clear way to do that on destop.